# Group by one column to get the total number of another column in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a table like this:

```
Size  Spring_type
Q     firm 
K     soft
K     soft
Q     medium
T     soft
S     medium
T     firm
```

and I want to identify which `spring_type` is the most prominent among each bed size. I think I can use the `group_by` to group the `size` but I'm not sure what to do to get the different`Spring_type` of each `size` respectively. Thank you.

Here is my desired table output:

```
Size  Spring_type type_total
Q     firm        1
Q     medium      1
K     soft        2
...
```

Comment: Try `group_by(Size, Spring_type)`

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 |> 
  group_by(Size, Spring_type) |> 
  summarise(type_total = n(), .groups = "drop")

#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   Size  Spring_type type_total
#>   <chr> <chr>            <int>
#> 1 K     soft                 2
#> 2 Q     firm                 1
#> 3 Q     medium               1
#> 4 S     medium               1
#> 5 T     firm                 1
#> 6 T     soft                 1
```

data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Size = c("Q", "K", "K", "Q", "T", "S", "T"), 
                      Spring_type = c("firm","soft", "soft", "medium", "soft", "medium", "firm")), 
                 class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>